# define error code, number or string?

Tags: java, error-handling, enterprise

When I use enterprise application, I am usually greeted by some error that needs to consult help desk. I found many application still lean to use number as error code instead of a human readable string. Given most enterprise applications are written in modern language like java/C#, I can not figure out what's the benefit in using numeric error code.

So the question is, for enterprise application, is there a common adopted pattern for defining error code? is any reason number preferred to string?

BTW: I understand application using REST API likely use http status code for error code, this is understood as http status code itself is number. but for others, I don't understand

Comment: Usually an error code goes with (i.e. is mapped to) an error string, no?

Comment: yes. error code usually maps to some description. so the question is, why do we need user to look up some table in daunting document or wiki for meaning of the magic numeric error code?. why not directly use a concise string as error code?

Answer (score 3):

It's usually convenient to have both, a code, numeric or otherwise, *and* something human-readable.

The code makes it easy for machines to know what happened (and serve as shorthand for humans), and is verbiage- and locale- independent.

Comment: Thanks Dave. locale- independent is a good point. but I don't think number is easier for machine as for language like Java/C#, string manipulation is trivial. The problem of numeric error code is it tightly couples your code. for example, if your application is plugable,  then each plugin has to be aware of what error code has been occupied by others. String error code has no such problem, it's very easy to create namespace.

Comment: @zx_wing Alphanumeric codes are also trivially namespaced. Localized or db-stored messages may change at arbitrary times. Parsing error messages is a recipe for disaster, and is unmaintainable in the long-term. You shouldn't have to parse anything when you can do a simple lookup.

Answer (score 2):

The single greatest benefit of error codes -- along with more informative strings -- is that they can be looked up even after your code has been translated into another language which you may not read.

The next greatest benefit is that if someone ever writes code that reads your error messages -- perhaps your own company, to help folks manage your appliction -- it is *tremendously* helpful for them to have an error code at the start of the message. That both speeds up their decision of what to do, and partially guards them against the risk that you might rephrase the message later (which would mess up attempts to search for the message text).

Any convention can work if you reliably stick with it. If you're thinking about the long term and multiple products, you'll probably want the code to include some indication of which code (application and/or library and/or other module) issued the error, and then you want to be able to quickly find the error in that product's support table.

IBM usually uses a moderately recognizable alphabetic prefix to identify the code, and a numeric suffix to indicate the specific message. Other companies probably do it differently.

Comment: Could you link me to IBM's error code convention? is that public? I am also thinking of using alphabetic prefix to create namespace for different components, in order to avoid conflict between plugins because numeric error code is flat. But a good question is, as I have started using alphabetic prefix, why not directly use string as error code?

Comment: As I said, other companies may do it differently.

My hesitation in using a string is the risk that, no matter how careful you are, some programmer will manage to pick a string which is rude in some language. It's a lot easier to pick a small number of prefixes than a large number of message identifiers. (Avoiding vowels doesn't completely solve it either. Think about how you'd feel if you got the error signified by NLCALCWTF.)

Comment: emm, "NLCALCWTF" enlightens me about verbiage- independent. it's often hard to describe an error in concise string. so it ends up to magic abbreviation or verbose sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I had recently similar problem and I have decided to use following rules:

- Similar errors are grouped in types (in Java these would be Exception Classes)
- Each error has enumerated value that identifies it (that is an error code)
- Each error has human readable message
- Errors optionally can have a cause (in many situations your errors were generated because some other error occurred, and that error is a cause)

You could argue about the need of the second rule since you could have as many types as possible errors. However if your system is growing, sooner or later you will find the need of introducing new types of errors, which will entail modification of your API and that's not always possible and even if it is, it might be not very easy since you will have to modify all of your clients. Enumerated error code list is simply easier to maintain in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `number`.

I didn't see a real answer here...There are many sources that suggest you should always use numeric values, one example:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html